# Cannot connect to node on windows server 2008R2

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-server-2008

I have 2 different instances of node running middleware (express) on a windows server.

The first one which I have been running for quite some time is at

```
http://judsondesigns.dyndns.org:3010/api/authenticate
```

If you do an options call in fiddler or postman to this API, you will get headers back.

I just setup another instance (server.js) which is the same exact code only different port:

```
http://judsondesigns.dyndns.org:3011/api/authenticate
```

When I hit this one I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I have opened ports 3010 and 3011 (TCP) on my firewall.

My file looks like this:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3011);
// express/connect middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next()
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('myApp server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Had to open that port on my router to incoming traffic. Hope this helps others.